# supporting view on different IOS devices.

Tags: xcode, autolayout, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, size-classes

1. My app is supposed to run only on Iphone but apple is testing it on Ipad too. Apparently, the apps can run in Iphone mode on Ipads. How do I know which Ipad will run which Iphone mode (ex: ipad mini air2 = iphone 5 view settings in iphone mode?)?
2. How can I change the size of my UI based on changing aspect ratio programmatically ? (My views are created through code).

Comment: Why do you want to know which ipad will run which ipad mode?

Comment: The problem is I am a newbie to Xcode. So far I have manage to create 3 different `views` for iphone4, iphone5, iphone 6 and they run fine once I detect which device is it. But when the app is put on ipad, UI's are disoriented. If I can detect which ipad runs in which phone mode, Probably I can solve this problem. Unless there is a better way to do it.

Comment: If you only want your app to run on iphones (As stated in the question), why are you trying ipads at all?

Comment: @HaydenHolligan, Its not me trying. Apple has a policy. Any iphone app can run on ipad (in iphone mode). Before releasing it to the store, Its one the things they test. They are asking us to fix the UI so that app can run in iphone mode on ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad Pro runs an iPhone 6. The iPad 2 and Air 2 run an iPhone 4s.

I don't know if there's official documentation for this, but what I did is create a sample app and set the Devices to iPhone only. Then I added

```
print(self.view.frame.size) //Swift
NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                  self.view.frame.size.height); //Obj-C
```

in the default ViewController. This will print the screen size of the view only, and not the entire iPad's screen. I then compared the printed value to the printed value of the same app run in iPhone 6/4s. You can try it too.

In terms of changing the size of your UI to fit different screen sizes, your best bet is probably AutoLayout. There are many (free, open source) frameworks available that make creating AutoLayout constraints programatically much simpler.

A few are [Stevia](https://github.com/s4cha/Stevia), [Cartography](https://github.com/robb/Cartography), [SnapKit (Swift)](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) / [Masonry (Obj-C)](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry), or [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up changing the UI based on frame %.

Answer (score 0):

As you said your app is supposed to run on iPhone only, then do the following process.

Select your project target in Xcode and goto General in which there is one section  Deployment Info

Change the Devices to **iPhone** from dropdown

[image]

this will open app on iPhone only.

Comment: Its already selected for iphone only. Like I said, you can still run iphone aps on ipas in iphone mode. thats what apple is doing while testing.